# Convert object to string with custom format

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have this:

```
[System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How can I convert it into `"3.4"`? I'm interested in piping it if possible to avoid having to create an intermediary variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider creating a Function for this that worked via Pipeline input:

```
Function ConvertTo-BuildRevision {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [system.version]
        $Version
    )
    Process {
        Return "$($Version.Build).$($Version.Revision)"
    }
}

[System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4) | ConvertTo-BuildRevision
```

This is obviously a lot more lines of code, but if you were performing this kind of conversion multiple times in your code would look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

this is *ugly* but it works inline fairly well. it uses the `.Split()` option to put the results into a specific number of items with all the remaining ones added to the last one.

```
([version]'1.2.3.4').ToString().Split('.', 3)[-1]
```

output = `3.4`

Answer (score 3):

Another ugly but inline solution, uses `ForEach-Object` to get at the piped reference.

```
[System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4) | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Build).$($_.Revision)" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, that uses `Select-Object` and a calculated property to get the result you want as a property named `BR` which is then returned:

```
([System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4) | Select @{N ='BR'; E = { "$($_.Build).$($_.Revision)" }}).BR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set it to a variable, you can do this:

```
$version = [System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4)
"$($version.Build).$($version.Revision)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)-based solution with the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator):

```
PS> [System.Version]::new(1, 2, 3, 4) -replace '^(.+?\.){2}'
3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper and adding a `ScriptProperty`:

```
Function New-Version {
    $Version = New-Object System.Version $Args
    $Version | Add-Member ScriptProperty BuildRevision {"$($This.Build).$($This.Revision)"} 
    Write-Output $Version
}
```

---

```
(New-Version 1 2 3 4).BuildRevision
3.4
```